# Problem with Deferreds -- Adding Custom Deferred Object to Array

Tags: jquery-deferred

I am trying to learn how to create custom Deferred objects and am working on the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/jhYjw/7/

Something must be up with jsFiddle, but when I run that code on my local browser, everything seems to work.

The deferreds are all called then the .done() is called.

However, there are no arguments passed in to the .done(). It's [] "result" in undefined.

What's going on? :P I'm passing in a string to resolveWith()

Thanks SO!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.resolveWith(x)`<sup>[[docs](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolveWith/)]</sup> doesn't pass `x` to your callbacks. It runs your callbacks with `this` set to `x`.

To pass `x` as the argument of your callback function use `.resolve(x)`<sup>[[docs](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolve/)]</sup>, or `.resolveWith(valueForThis, x)`.